# jquery click function already clicked/executed on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following function:

```
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('#login-trigger').click(function()
        {
            $(this).next('#login-content').slideToggle();
            $(this).toggleClass('active');          

            if ($(this).hasClass('active')) $(this).find('span')
            else $(this).find('span')
        })
    });
```

When someone clicks a certain button, a login form drops down. However, if they type the incorrect login information and the page reloads with an error message below the form, how can I make its like button has already been clicked and the form is displayed? Right now, if they type in the wrong information, the page reloads and they are not logged in. To see the error, you must click to drop down the login form to see the error. This would confuse most people and doesn't make much sense.

Comment: make [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question:

First of all what does this:

```
if ($(this).hasClass('active')) $(this).find('span')
            else $(this).find('span')
```

if it has the .active class then find the span, and if it didn't then find the span anyway? and then do what with it?

Secondly, in an stateless mode you can't retrieve the information of any type (like for example if the user has tried to login already or not) from the last session, so you need to either have it don in your back-end (PHP, Node, etc.) or save the data on users browser (cookies, localstorage) which in your case (authentication) is **NOT** recommended.

So you're gonna need to let your server answer to your Login request, then according to its answer, use JavaScript (or even simpler and more preferably CSS) to show a visual presentation to user, and NEVER try to check for the validation of the user login information in front-end.

I hope it helps.

Comment: I use PHP to check if a username or password is incorrect which then reloads the page with a message below the login form that says either "invalid username" or "invalid password". I am just trying to figure out how I can have the form already dropped down when this happens. All this function does is slide the form in and out when someone clicks the login button. I want the form to already be showing upon the page reload when they type the wrong login info

Comment: Where in doing that you have a problem?
--------------------------
There are two parts:
1. check for the existence of the element

2. opening the form

to check the existence of the element you can use JQuery and to help you to know how to open the form accordingly we need to see your form and interaction code.

Also I would suggest to don't tell the user what they entered wrong (password or username), just tell them either of them or both were wrong without any more information what so ever!